# Export Stretch Function values - Arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcpy, export, stretch

I'm looking for a way to export Stretch Function values from images that’s stored in a Mosaic dataset. Not values from the whole set, but specific stretch functions per image. The set is stored in either a filegeodatabase or SDE.

The values I’m looking for is eg. Band[] Min, Max, Mean values and Gamma values....

EditRasterFunction_management() allows me to insert, update or delete which I’ve used to initially create the Stretch Function.

But after some manual editing for the raster images I need a way to export the new values.
I can’t manage to get access to this information using cursors since it’s a function?

Any ideas how to maintain this function values?

Preferably using Arcpy/python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Get Raster Properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m7000000) tool?

As always at the bottom of the page are examples of using the tool with Python.

Comment: Get Raster Properties gives me values for the whole Mosaic Dataset, not for a specific image. Maybe wasnt so clear about that.

Comment: @toge You can use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with additional details at any time.